# Place 2 elements per div side-by-side in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array like this:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

And I want to place them as 2 per one line in two dimensional divs. Let me illustrate what im trying to say:

This is main React element:

```
render() {
  return <div className="base">{...}</div>
}
```

Expected Result:

```
render() {
  return <div className="base">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="left">
                <span>1</span>
                <span>2</span>
              </div>
              <div className="right">
                <span>3</div>
                <span>4</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="left">
                <span>5</span>
                <span>6</span>
              </div>
              <div className="right">
                <span>7</div>
                <span>8</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="container">
              <div className="left">
                <span>9</span>
                {/* no 10th element because 9 is the last. */}
              </div>
              {/* no right div because no more elements. */}
            </div>

         </div>
}
```

If this was a typical odd even situation, I would do `i % 2` here. However, how am i going to close div tag on odd or even? But it is a bit more complicated than that. Is there any way to achieve this in React? I'm using TypeScript by the way and latest ReactJS.

Comment: map the array and use grid styling.

Comment: That is the problem. I have no idea how to place them 2-by-2 in base container via right and left. How do I make them with grids? Any sample maybe? Thanks.

Comment: chunk your array, then map with an inner map. tada, you got what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to render more advanced loops in react, you need to get used to chunking your arrays. you can simply chunk the array twice using the following function, then you can map this array recursively to render your desired output:

```
function chunk_array(arr,chunkSize=2) {
  const result=[];
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i+=chunkSize) {
    result.push(arr.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
  }
  return result;
}
```

**NOTE: I made a JS fiddle so you can visualize how this array changes to become the shape we need to render your desired html output ** [JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nxa9wqe0/1/)

now you can utilize this in render to accomplish what you want.

```
import React from 'react';

function chunk_array(arr,chunkSize=2) {
    const result=[];
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i+=chunkSize) {
        result.push(arr.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
    }
    return result;
}

const arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

const chunked = chunk_array(chunk_array(arr));// we chunk array twice to get desired structure.

class Example extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {chunked.map((container,i)=>(
                    <div className="base" key={i}>
                    {container.map((row,i2)=>(
                    <div key={i2} className={(i2===0?"left":"right")}>
                        {row.map((item,i3)=><span key={i3}>{item}</span>)}
                    </div>))}
                </div>))}
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in some ways but here is a sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-joliot-lkdxq

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const Result = () => {
  return (arr.map(item => {
    return (
      <div key={item} className="box">
        {item}
      </div>
    );
  }));
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Result />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the css:

```
.App {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;

}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. However, This is what I already tried. This is not what I want. I want 2 items per div. 2 items to left 2 items to right. and wrap this left and right div with wrapper (`.container`) . Please see the **Expected Result**

Comment: You know what. I just tried and applied your custom css and i think i can use it. Thanks for the answer especially on CSS part.

Comment: I think you want this. https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-snowflake-tdzjn?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answer you are looking for:
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-snowflake-tdzjn?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const Result = () => {
  return arr.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      index % 2 === 0 && (
        <div key={item} className="box">
          <span>{arr[index]}</span>
          <span>{arr[index + 1]}</span>
        </div>
      )
    );
  });
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Result />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the css:

```
.App {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;

}

.box {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px black solid;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box span {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: **Exactly!** Both of your answer are accepted. I will use CSS (your first answer) wherever possible and second answer on this case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap to do this. Put the everything inside a div className="row" and then have each of the items have className="col-6". Bootstrap cuts every row into 12 columns, so giving each element 6 of those columns will cause them to be 2 on a line as you want. You'll need to npm install bootstrap and include the appropriate script tags in your application. Take a look here, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Bootstrap will visually split. Yes. However, I am trying to split them via elements. So that i can put other stuff in it. And i cannot use bootstrap.from npm. :(